# StatusDescription Encoding in HttpResponse

Tags: c#, asp.net, encoding, httpresponse

I am using C# and write to HttpResponse StatusDescription the error message in case an exception occurs. Internal i use another service that returns error descriptions in russian unfortunately. And this russian error messages i have to return in HttpResponse StatusDescrition. I use UTF-8 encoding and write this way:

```
var message = exception.Message.Substring(0, Math.Min(exception.Message.Length, 512));
var encodedBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

response.StatusDescription = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encodedBytes);
```

But this doesn't help. In Fiddler it seems something wrong with enconding:

> HTTP/1.1 500 Could not update reservation. Error message: ����������� ������ �� �������������

What should i do to enable russian symbols?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you are not using UTF-8 encoding. You are using it to encode and decode the string before you use it, so that step is pointless. Your code does the same as:

```
response.StatusDescription =
  exception.Message.Substring(0, Math.Min(exception.Message.Length, 512));
```

Anyway, you can't use UTF-8 encoding for the HTTP headers, they are just plain text. Put the error message in the response body instead, as you can specify an encoding for that.

Comment: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.headerencoding(v=VS.90).aspx)

Comment: Sorry, but here they say HttpResponse headers use UTF-8 encoding by default: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.headerencoding(v=VS.90).aspx. I cann't understand anything! And how it would be the proper way to get the string in UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: @WabiSabi: If the header encoding really was UTF-8, then that setting would have to be sent in the header, as UTF-8 is not the encoding specified in the HTTP standard, but there is nothing about the header encoding in the header that is sent. The `HeaderEncoding` controls how the headers are encoded, but it's not useful when you send the response to a regular browser. You can use the `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` method to encode a string as UTF-8, but then it's not a string any more, but a byte array.

Comment: Guffa, thank you for your swift answers! The matter is this response is not for sending to a browser, but to web applications for request. And these applications should be knowning the reasons of errors that occurs. And i try to check myself it with Fiddler. But the russian messages are not readable.

Comment: @WabiSabi: Fiddler uses the standard for decoding the response, so it won't handle headers with a custom encoding. You can send unicode in the headers if the applications knows how to decode it, but that means that the applications have to handle the HTTP protocol themselves and not use a standard library.

Comment: I've found out an interesting thing! I've added a response header with the same error message string in russian in UTF8 encoding. And you know, fiddler shows it in a proper way! It seems to me that StatusDescription uses some other encoding, as you've mentioned before. But i don't understand what you meant under the 'plain text'. I would like to follow the standards as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a way to do this: encoding it as a URI string.

```
Response.StatusDescription = Uri.EscapeUriString("Your message here");
```

You will have to decode the response on the client side in ECMAScript:

`decodeURIComponent(r.statusText)`